# AWS storage class change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some files in my AWS S3 bucket which i would like to put in Glacier Deep Archive from Standard Storage. After selecting the files and changing the storage class, it gives the following message.

Since the message says that it will make a copy of the files, my question is that will I be charged extra for moving my existing files to another storage class?

Thanks.

"This action creates a copy of the object with updated settings and a new last-modified date. You can change the storage class without making a new copy of the object using a lifecycle rule.

Objects copied with customer-provided encryption keys (SSE-C) will fail to be copied using the S3 console. To copy objects encrypted with SSE-C, use the AWS CLI, AWS SDK, or the Amazon S3 REST API."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, changing the storage class incurs costs, regardless of whether it's done manually or via a lifecycle rule.

If you do it via the console, it will create a deep archive copy but will retain the existing one as a previous version (if you have versioning enabled), so you'll start being charged for storage both (until you delete the original version).

If you do it via a lifecycle rule, it will transition (not copy) the files, so you'll only pay for storage for the new storage class.

In both cases, you'll have to pay for LIST ($0.005 per 1000 objects in `STANDARD` class) and COPY/PUT ($0.05 per 1000 objects going to `DEEP_ARCHIVE` class) actions.

Since data is being moved within the same bucket (and therefore within the same region), there will be no data transfer fees.

The only exception to this pricing is the "[intelligent tiering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-intelligent-tiering/)" class, which automatically shifts objects between storage classes based on frequency of access and does not charge for shifting classes.

> No additional tiering fees apply when objects are moved between access tiers within the S3 Intelligent-Tiering storage class.

Comment: Thank you. But i only see 1 copy of the file in the bucket which is in the Glacier Deep Archive . Where would the original file be?

Comment: I believe you would see it as a previous version of the file (assuming you have versioning enabled). If you don't have versioning enabled, then the new copy will have overwritten the old copy. Sorry, I should have been more clear about that in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I don't have versioning enabled. Since I don't have versioning enabled I should be good and I don't have to delete any previous copies correct? Also lets say I am changing 4000 files from standard to Glacier Deep Archive, I will be charged $0.2 (0.05 * 4 ) ? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you would be charged a `LIST` for each file ($0.005 * 4), and `COPY` for each file ($0.05 * 4) for a total of $0.22.

Comment: Thank you. And if I setup an intelligent tiering, then I wont be even charged the $0.22?

Comment: In theory, no, but (a) it will only apply to new files (existing files will have a cost to transition them to intelligent tiering), and (b) there are other limitations such as a minimum file size. I suggest you read the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) on it.